# How should I organize my files in Xcode?

Tags: xcode4, code-organization

I have about 5 XIBs and a ~50 of .m/.h files.

I've seen some people put all of their headers into a "Headers" folder.  Is this a good idea?  Will Xcode still be able to swap between header/source when I do the key-combo?

This is a 1-developer project.

What are some other hints?  I know the motto "whatever works best for you", but I might not know what's better so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to keep matching .h and .m together, and group them by functionality, with folders that match the group structure of the project.

Comment: Agreed.  I only do a header folder when I've got multiple programs that use the same set of functionality.  Like a utilities set or similar.